# Add a popup dialog over the call screen

Tags: java, android

How do I add a popup dialog over the call screen? I'll be using the `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for incoming calls and show it. I need an idea about how to write an activity that allows a dialog over an incoming call. Also, how do I make the dialog movable to any part of the screen? I already have the `BroadcastRceiver` implemented and performing other functions, so I could just use an intent and start the activity from this `BroadcastRceiver`

Answer (score 0):

start an activity, then use AlertDialog Builder from that activity to prompt a dialog

set custom view to customize the dialog appearence

Comment: How do I make the dialog movable over the call screen? And I'd also like to have it cancelled by dragging it out of the screen.

Comment: you can refer to this thread about creating modal overlay 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top

Comment: Thanks that helps. But how do I make it floatable so I can drag it anywhere on the screen?

Comment: once a system overlay is created on screen, you can setOnTouchListener on the layout container (not the buttons). Check the action in onTouch(), see whether it's MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE or ACTION_UP, and determine the x y of the system overlay

Comment: Could you provide an example? I can't wrap my head around an activity having only a dialog box. What kind of XML layout would it use? No hurries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context.getApplicationContext());
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.caller_dialog, null);

            ImageView button = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.close_btn);
            builder.setView(dialogView);
            final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE);
            alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            alert.show();
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            Window window = alert.getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
            window.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
            lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
            //This makes the dialog take up the full width
            lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            window.setAttributes(lp);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //close the service and remove the from from the window
                    alert.dismiss();
                }
            });
```